# Работа со строка и файлами С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Помогите решить задачу.

> С помощью текстового редактора создать файл содержащий текст, длина которого не превышает 1000 символов, длина строк текста не должна превышать 70 символов. Написать программу, которая выводит содержание файла на экран, определить количество символов в самом коротком слове, по нажатию произвольной клавиши поочередно выделять каждое слово текста, содержащие минимальное количество символов.

Мне удалось только сделать вывод информации из файла на экран:

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ".ACP");    
    ifstream file("text.DAT", "r");    
    cout << file.rdbuf();
    //file.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;    
}
```

Что дальше? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

[@Ольга 08](/users/10241/%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B3%D0%B0-08), попробуйте подойти к задаче несколько по другому.

Посмотрите, основной целью является **выделение очередного самого короткого слова** по нажатию клавиши (и очевидно вывод этого слова на экран). Перед этим от Вас хотят вывода всего файла и длины самого короткого слова. Очевидно, что самых коротких слов может быть несколько.

Также важной информацией из условия задачи является утверждение о длине файла (1000). Это Вам поможет, можно не строить динамические структуры данных, а обосновано предположить, что *самых коротких слов* может набраться не более 500.

Теперь определите для себя, что такое слово. Для простоты предположите, что это несколько символов, разделенных одним или более разделителями (пробел, табуляция, символ(ы) конца строки).

Таким образом, Вам нужно читать файл по словам. Это просто. Думаю, вы уже читали `cin` в переменную типа `string`. Вот и делайте это в цикле, пока файл не закончится. Получение длины слова очевидно.

Далее Вы определяете, является ли очередное слово *самым коротким* из ранее прочитанных (т.е. короче еще не было) и если это так, то помещаете его **в первый элемент** массива самых коротких слов и отмечаете что в этом массиве одно слово (например в переменной `n = 1`). Если прочитанное слово оказывается *очередным самым коротким*, то добавляете его к массиву (поместите в элемент массива `n` и увеличьте`n`). По ходу дела вычисляете длину самого короткого (самых коротких) слова.

Понятно, что задача разделяется на 3 легко реализуемых части. Первую - вывод файла на экран - Вы сделали. Вывод прямо из буфера - дело в принципе хорошее (надо стремиться к эффективности даже на С++). По хорошему ее надо улучшить, чтобы можно было копировать файлы любой длины (т.е. длиннее буфера) и реализовать вывод в цикле.

Вторая часть, это повторное считывание файла по словам, вычисление длины самого короткого слова и размещение этих слов в массиве string.

Третья часть - печать этого массива по одному элементу при нажатии клавиши.

Вот, собственно, и все решение. (теперь можете задавать более мелкие вопросы (если при реализации какой-то из частей возникнут проблемы)).

Успехов.